# JCycle and Drupal 7 not working correctly

Tags: jcycle

I have a problem with the jQuery Cycle plugin in Drupal 7...

I use the following jQuery code to insert the div's and than the functionality of the cycle plugin :

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<div id="slideshowContainer">'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<div class="slideshow">'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<img src="images/image1.png" width="600" height="300"/>'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<img src="images/image2.png" width="600" height="300"/>'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<img src="images/image3.png" width="600" height="300"/>'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<img src="images/image4.png" width="600" height="300"/>'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<img src="images/image5.png" width="600" height="300"/>'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('</div>'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<ul id="nav">'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<li id="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('<li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('</ul>'); 
$("#homepage_pics").append('</div>'); 

$('.slideshow').cycle({fx: 'fade', pause: 1, prev: '#prev', next: '#next'}); 
})
```

He shows the pictures but the cycle plugin does not work.
I use Drupal 7 with artisteer 4. I don't use the View module and the version of JQuery is 1.8.2
Can anyone help me ?

Thanks